# Mongoose: bug with the $or operator?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm having some problems with the **$or** operator. I'm making a *somewhat* complex **query** that looks like this:

```
Tag.findOne({  
    '$and' : [ { 
        '$or' : [ { 
                'number' : tags[i] 
            }, { 
                'title.english' : tags[i] 
            }, { 
                'title.japanese' : tags[i] 
            } ] } , {
        'properties.status' : 'published'
    } ] }, 
function(e, tag) {
//...
```

My **Schema** looks like this:

```
var tagSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        english: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true, max: 50 },
        japanese: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true, max: 50 },
        alternative: [{ type: String, trim: true, max: 50 }]
},
//...
     number: Number,
});
```

If I use it like this only if **'number'** equals **tags[i]** I get a result, but not for either **title properties**.
If I now remove

```
{ 'number' : tags[i] },
```

Both **title properties** work. I had the same problem when I used the **'_id'** property instead of **'number'** and I really do not see the problem.

**So what is the issue with this query?**

Comment: Do you get any error when you use the `number` line inside `$or`?

Comment: @Cristy No I don't get any errors, but it just seems to ignore the other two values.

Comment: So the `e` variable is `undefined` in the callback function?

Comment: @Cristy Oh I just now added console.error(e) and I do get [CastError: Cast to number failed for value "manga" at path "number"]
So I guess I have to check if it's a string before I pass it to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `{ 'number' : tags[i] },` with `{ 'number' : isNaN(tags[i]) ? 0 : tags[i] },`

So if the tag is not a number you don't get an error trying to cast it. When it is `NaN` I used `0` but you could use whatever value can't appear as the `number` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer.